# Condense multiple mysql queries that are run only if previous query has no result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to run a series of queries where the next is only run if the previous give no result.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE a_id = "value" AND x_id = "samevalue" ORDER BY rand LIMIT 1;
```

ONLY if there are no results with A_ID try with B_ID

```
SELECT * from tbl WHERE b_id = "othervalue" AND x_id = "samevalue" ORDER BY rand LIMIT 1;
```

ONLY if there are no results with B_ID, try with just X_ID

```
SELECT * from tbl WHERE x_id = "samevalue" ORDER BY rand LIMIT 1;
```

I am trying to reduce the number of calls to the database and/or increase speed with for example prepared statements.

But using for example OR

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE 
     (a_id = "value" AND x_id = "samevalue") 
  OR (b_id = "othervalue" AND x_id = "samevalue") 
  OR x_id = "samevalue" ORDER BY rand LIMIT 1;
```

Would return a random match from a set of all the matching OR statements (if for example a_id and b_id both matched).

My first thought was to speed the multiple queries up using prepared statements, but can prepared statements include columns that are ignored?

```
$mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl (a_id, b_id, x_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
```

then bind and run the queries, but I can't see it working as it would require all three variables, no? And preparing before each query would be pointless as each query would be run only once.

My mysql skills are fairly limited and my google skills have also proved fruitless for the last 2.5 hours.

**Some added business logic:**

File will receive URI elements which will be pulled by $_GET
- accepted elements are: country (a_id), continent (b_id) and children (x_id)
- children is required and execution will halt if not present.
- country and continent is optional

table: persons
column: country
column: continent
column: children

if country is set: return a random person where country = a_id AND children = x_id

if country query returns no result or country isn't set and continent is set:  return random person from where continent = b_id and children = x_id

if continent query returns no result or country and continent isn't set:   return random person where children = x_id

Comment: Try to post a real example, not artificial one. There is a chance that your database structure is wrong and you will need to redesign it.

Comment: I haven't build the real database structure yet as I do not know how it would be built properly. What I have at this point is this dummy table where I am running tests.

Comment: But you have some business logic in mind. which should be reflected in the table and field names.

Comment: I tried adding some business logic. does that help?

Comment: I think you should stick to three queries.

Comment: This file might get a lot of requests, for the sake of argument lets exaggerate and say its accessed 100 times per second. making it 300 queries per second in the worst case. Would there not be massive performance benefits of being able to condense this into a single query? Bringing me back to the original question: how would this be accomplished.

Comment: No. By no means there is no such thing like "massive performance benefits" of being able to condense three queries into one. You are way overestimating a query execution overhead. It is not as big or even noticeable as you fear. Quite contrary, it is somethein as natural as breathing. Just run it. Besides, it won't be 3 queries all the time.

Comment: As long as your queries run fast, it shouldn't be a problem. But if your queries are slow, then you should make them fast, not condensing three slow queries into one tree times slower